# menubar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How do we create horizontal menubar in asp.net?

I want to create the menubar to contain links, clicking on which only the matter below the menubar should change.

I am beginning to learn web development. Please guide me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.NET `Menu` (`<asp:Menu ... >`) control and set the `Orientation` property to `Horizontal`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<asp:Menu ID="TopMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="MenuSource" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="0" DynamicVerticalOffset="0"
            DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" />
```